# Rental server refuses SSH connection; won't allow authorise me to download my SSH key

Tags: ssh, wget, webserver, key-authentication, ssh-config

I am attempting to connect to my rental server via ssh to install MemSQL for a project. I have written the following in ~/.ssh/config:

```
HOST eHosts
HostName e9.ehosts.com
Port 2222
User orderof3
```

But receive the following error:

```
Connection closed by 108.167.160.55
```

I have copied the details exactly as suggested by my server company, but to no avail.

I thought this might be because the SSH key hasn't been downloaded, so I ran wget with my username and password listed after the --user and --password flags, respectively. However, when I did so I received the following error:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting     response... 401 Access Denied
Unknown authentication scheme.

Username/Password Authentication     Failed.
```

Now, I am currently using a Linux partition without access to any sort of graphical user  interface, so the usual browser-based method of downloading the RSA key(s) doesn't work.

Oddly, running nmap shows port 2222 as 'EtherNetIP-1' and port 22 as ssh, though 2222 was definitely the address given.

The ssh command I am running is:

```
ssh eHosts
```

Running:

```
ssh eHosts -vv
```

Results in the following output:

[image: Output Part 1]

[image: Output Part 2]

[image: Output Part 3]

Comment: Have you opened port 2222/TCP in the self-provisioning interface of your VPS provider?

Comment: The tech support lady said she had opened it herself, and nmap showed the port is currently open, though the port I was told to use shows as being assigned to an Ethernet connection rather than ssh (port 22 does show as being an ssh port).

Comment: Can you show the `ssh` command you're running and also run it with `-vv `and include the output in the question.

Comment: I took some photos but they didn't turn out too well. Instead I've booted into Window -- will run my Tumbleweed VM from there and copy-paste the results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I had to do was to use PuTTY as the server seems to be configured in such a way as to only allow access through PuTTY. At least, this is my current workaround, though I would rather have access from my openSUSE partition command-line.

Comment: That sounds like you have ssh key-based authentication configured, but that only PuTTY has the local (private) half of the key.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter I had now found the question seems to be a little more complex than it would first appear. If it is a PuTTY only access issue it's not nearly as simple as my answer would imply. I would probably downvote my own answer if I could... although that seems a little harsh for a genuinely good faith question... hmmm, investigation continues...